# AssertionFailedError when output is identical

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assert

Contents of expected and actual output is identical, but I get `org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError`

I have tried to replace all `/n` with `System.lineSeparator()` but the output I get is: **"contents have differences only in line separators"**

```
  @BeforeEach
    public void setUpStreamsAndEmptyFile() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));

        // emptying file contents
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filePath);
            pw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void restoreStreams() {
        System.setOut(originalOut);
        System.setErr(originalErr);
    }

    @Test
    public void executeCreateEventCommand() {
        String expected = "\t Got it. I've added this task: " + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\t  [Event][✗] Project Meeting (at: 28/08/19 1600 - 28/08/19 1800)" + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\t Now you have 1 task in the list" + System.lineSeparator();

        CreateEventCommand command = new CreateEventCommand("Project Meeting /at 28/08/19 1600 - 28/08/19 1800");
        try {
            command.execute(tasks, ui, storage);
        } catch (DukeException e) {
            System.out.println("execute create event command test should pass, but it didn't " + e.getMessage());
        }

        assertEquals(expected, outContent.toString());
    }
```

Comment: just checked the debugger and it seems that there are some `/r` in my expected but not my actual.

Comment: don't assert on the exact message, but assert that the result has your event title in as a substring and there is `Now you have 1 task` substring as well. Your test will be very fragile if you are asserting that strings have to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can try to check whether there are multiple substrings in your result. You could do that with `assertThat` and [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/UsesOfHamcrest). So you can avoid the line separators.

```java
import org.hamcrest.core.StringContains;
import org.junit.Assert;

...

String expectedSubString1 = "Got it. I've added this task:"; 
String expectedSubString2 = "[Event][✗] Project Meeting (at: 28/08/19 1600 - 28/08/19 1800)";
String expectedSubString3 = "Now you have 1 task in the list";

...
String result = outContent.toString();
Assert.assertThat(result, StringContains.containsString(expectedSubString1));
Assert.assertThat(result, StringContains.containsString(expectedSubString2));
Assert.assertThat(result, StringContains.containsString(expectedSubString3));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not include tabs or line separators in your expected, and would replace all of them too in your `outContent.toString()` before comparing:

```
final String cleanOutput = outContent.toString().replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "");
assertEquals(expected, cleanOutput);
```

what about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is a symptom of a greater issue. This is just a perfect example of why you should basically never assert on complex strings. Focus more on tests around whether the task is created properly, not what message you are displaying to the user. That is prone to change way too often to be asserting on it.

Think about what you want it to mean when that test comes back as a failure.